# mod_rewrite URLs

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite URLs so when someone goes to:

```
url.com/directory1/directory2
```

He sees the URL in the browser address bar but actually the following URL is showing the text

```
url.com/index.php/directory1/directory2
```

So basically, the URL `url.com/directory1/directory2` goes to `url.com/index.php/directory1/directory2`

How can I do that using .htaccess and/or mod_rewrite? What is the rewrite rule for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your .htacces file use this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)(\/?)$ /index.php/$1/$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

**OR** in your httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/"
    ServerName www.url.com   
    ServerAlias www.url.com
    <Directory /path/to/www/> 
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
        RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)(\/?)$ /index.php/$1/$2 [NC,QSA,L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If you use PHP:

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will have `/asd/asd`

Comment: It give me access denied pal